# how to fake a click on a dynamic element?

Tags: ajax, jquery

On a static element, to fake a click, I use

```
$(selector).click();
```

But how can I do the same thing on a dynamic element (resulted from an ajax call)?

Comment: make sure that the new element has an ID or Class you can use as element reference and you can use the same way you trigger any regular element. like in your example.

Comment: it's hard to do this because it is too long and related to alot of other complicated things. It's a real life project.

Comment: Is the element a variable containing multiple elements gathered during page load ?

Comment: Did you check my updated answer with the DEMO?

Answer (score 3):

The same...:

```
$(selector).click();
```

Why didn't you try it first?

P.S. it is not called *fake* a click, it's called *trigger* the click event.

```
$(selector).trigger('click'); == $(selector).click();
```

---

**Update**

You need to bind that element a callback to the event in order it to work:

```
$(selector).click(function(){...});
$(selector).click();
```

If you want it to have the the `click` callback you assigned to the static elements automaticlly,  you should use `on`\ `delegate` (or `live` but it's deprecated) when you attach the click callback.

```
$('body').on('click', 'selector', function(){...})
```

instead if  `body` use the closest static element the holds that selector elements.

See my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx2h7/)**

Comment: I tried, but i didnt work.
.click() is just for static element, not dynamic

Comment: @LeoLerdorf. That is not true. Your selector **must be** wrong. Check it: `alert($(selector).length);` . Are you sure you binded it an event???

Comment: thanks, i bound an event for it using .live('click', callback() {//blah blah}) (it's deprecated but still works well). Then I call $(selector).click(); but nothing happen

Comment: @LeoLerdorf. I added a demo to my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

within your ajax success function try your code:

```
$(selector).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand (I'm french sorry...)

But try :

```
 $(selector).live('click',function(){}); // deprecated it seems
```

Demo of gdoron with live() : http://jsfiddle.net/Rx2h7/1/

Comment: Those two lines do totally two different things!

Comment: Sorry, but when I load dynamic content with ajax, click() doesn't work anymore, but live('click'... works like a charm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Comment: @Valky - The first one is just another way of writing click(), it is not live, delegated or anything else, for that you would need to do something like this: `$(someParent).on('click', 'selector', function(){});`

Comment: I added a demo to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Your first line equals to `$(selector).click(function(){...})` it's not dynamic at all!

Comment: Updated, happy ? If not, I could erase my answer tried. Then, now, you will earn your up votes and validate answer, don't worry you'll be gratified like a master...

Answer (score 0):

Basing this on your previous question : [How can I select a list of DOM objects render from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348097/how-can-i-select-a-list-of-dom-objects-render-from-an-ajax-call/9348899#comment11804186_9348899)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var listItems = $('#myList li a');
     var containers = $('#myContainer > div');

     listItems.click(function(e){//do someting
     });

etc...
```

If the elements you are trying to attach a click handler to are supposed to be inside any of the two variables above then you WILL have to update those variables after the elements are inserted into the DOM, as it is right now only elements that exists during first page load will be inside those variables.

That is the only reason I can think of why something like :

```
$(document).on('click', listItems, function(e) {//do something
});
```

will not work!

Answer (score 0):

use on() method of jquery,

**staticElement.on('click', selector, function(){})**

**on** method generates click event on dynamically created element by attaching it to the static element present in the DOM .

For further reference check this out -- https://api.jquery.com/on/